# NSPredicate for array of dictionaries, and the dict has a value of array

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have an array with dictionaries. The dictionary has a value of array, like:

```
{ @"categories" : [@"equipment", @"weapon", @"sword"] }
```

I want to find out all the dictionaries in that array whose categories contains weapon, I tried:

```
NSString *category = @"weapon";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.categories contains %@", category];
NSArray *resultArray = [dictionaryArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But resultArray is empty.
How can I do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
NSString *category = @"weapon";
NSArray *items = @[@{ @"categories" : @[@"equipment", @"weapon", @"sword"] },
                    @{ @"categories" : @[@"toys", @"weapon", @"sword"] },
                    @{ @"categories" : @[@"arrow", @"bow", @"sword"] }];
NSPredicate*predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSArray *categories = [evaluatedObject objectForKey:@"categories"];
    return [categories containsObject:category];
}];
NSArray *filteredArray = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

In my case it outputs like,

```
(
{
    categories =     (
        equipment,
        weapon,
        sword
    );
},
{
    categories =     (
        toys,
        weapon,
        sword
    );
}
```